# jquery-mobile-iscrollview scroll bar position not correct in phonegap android

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, iscroll

I am using jquerymobile.1.3.1 for my phonegap android app. I am added [jquery-mobile-iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview)

But scrollbar position is wrong in the screen.
My HTML Code:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="g" id="mobile_page">    
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="g" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
       <img src="images/logo/logowhite.png" class="main_logo">
      <h3 class="page_heading">Select The Item</h3>
      <img src="images/header.png" class="header_right_btn header_home_btn">
      <div id="header_form">
            <div class="progressbar">
                <div class="progress active"></div>
                <div class="progress active"></div>
                <div class="progress"></div>
                <div class="progress"></div>
                <div class="progress"></div>
            </div><!-- progressbar end -->

            <div class="ui-grid-b top_form">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <select data-role="none" class="form_select_top" style="border:none">
                        <option value="op">Option 1</option>
                    </select>                    
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <select data-role="none" class="form_select_top">
                        <option value="op">Option 1</option>
                    </select>                    
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <select data-role="none" class="form_select_top">
                        <option value="op">Option 1</option>
                    </select>                    
                </div>
            </div>          
      </div>
    </div><!--header end-->   

    <div data-role="content" data-iscroll="">        

        <ul class="mobile_list_step_two">
            <li>
                <div class="_imag"></div>
                <div class="_company"></div>
                <h2 class="name_header"></h2>
                <h3 class="name_sube_header"></h3>
                <h3 class="name_sube_header"></h3>
                <h1 class="_price"></h1>
                <div class="collapsible_step_two">
                    <div class="collapse_content_step_two">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a">
                                <button data-role="none" class="collapsecontent_btn">Whats Included ?</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align:right;">
                                <button data-role="none" class="collapsecontent_btn">Information</button>
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <button data-role="none" class="collapse_btn_step_two"><img src="images/collapseopen.png" id="collapse_icon"></button>
                </div>                       
            </li>               
        </ul>

    </div><!--content end-->    
    <div data-role="footer" class="footer_style" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="footer_style" data-grid="c">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="id_1" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="id_2" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="id_3" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="id_4" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--Page End-->
```

Comment: Post some code! What does your markup look like? Which element is the mobile scroll view plugin binding to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Your current versions of jQM and iScroll versions..
But am not sure. :-)
May be u did some changes in ur current Js files. in Acutal cases it will not happns !
So please set the jQM settings as default (Replace your current jQM to default jQM js)

Comment: Yes! i did changed  some default settings in jqm.js

Comment: So still your problem exists?>